# jQuery on ( ) , why does 'click' on another unattached element take place?

Tags: jquery

html snippet :

```
<p>add more</p>
<div class="display_box_ppl_tag" style="border:1px solid red; width:120px; text-align:center;">
    this is the display box text
</div>
```

js snippet :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click', $(".display_box_ppl_tag"), function(e) {
        //$(".display_box_ppl_tag").on('click',function(){
        e.stop Propagation();
        alert("yes clicked");
    });

    $('p').click(function() {

        $('.display_box_ppl_tag:last').after('<div class="display_box_ppl_tag">this is display box ppl tag</div>');

    });

});​
```

What is intended through the code is, clicking on `</p>` will add a new element with the class 'display_box_ppl_tag' after the existing ones with the same class name, and clicking on any of the divs with  class 'display_box_ppl_tag' will launch an alert box. But when ever `</p>` is clicked , the alert box is launched without any click on the said div.

1. Why does this happen?

   Again if change the following line

   ```
   $(document).on('click',$(".display_box_ppl_tag"),function(e){
   ```

   to

   ```
   $('.display_box_ppl_tag').on('click',function(){,
   ```

   the 'click' event is not attached to the newly created elements. But from the [API](http://api.jquery.com/on/) , I find  'If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.'
2. Why does not the later coding work as expected ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want:

```
$(document).on('click', '.display_box_ppl_tag', function(){
```

This is saying the event should fire when you click on a '.display_box_ppl_tag' (including new elements with this class) that is a child of the document.

The first one:

```
$(document).on('click',$(".display_box_ppl_tag"),function(e){
```

is just incorrect syntax because the second argument isn't "A selector string" (see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)).  I'm not sure how jQuery interprets this, but it may just be equivalent to:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
```

which would trigger on any click.

As you said, the second:

```
$('.display_box_ppl_tag').on('click',function(){,
```

will have no effect on newly created elements.  This is specified in the docs as "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()."

Comment: with the selector in correct format, the code gives expected output. Why won't the second code (i.e: $('.display_box_ppl_tag').on('click',function(){,) work ? if the corrected code attach event handlers to the newly created ones, why won't the second code do that?

Comment: I gave the relevant doc quote for the second one.  Basically, with that one, you're adding the event directly only to those events *currently* matching the selector.

Comment: I mean "those elements currently matching"

Comment: trying to understand.. ' you're adding the event directly only to those events currently matching the selector' - why doesn't it apply to the first code?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed, in the first one, you're adding it only to the `document` that now exists, but saying that it should fire for descendants (current or existing) of document that match `.display_box_ppl_tag`.

Comment: 'for descendants (current or existing) of...' - then how is the even attached to the newly created ones?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed, I misspoke in the comment. "(current or existing)"  should have been "(current or future)".  With the first line, it's not *attached* to either current or future descendants.  It's just attached to the `document`, but through event delegation (simliar to the old [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method) fires for current or future descendants.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how the events bubble up.  In your second line, you're essentially creating a handler when the event bubbles up to a particular element.  New elements won't be children of this element, so the event won't bubble up to it.

If you want to capture new elements, in your initial selector, use a parent element (such as `document`).